# Android app has permission "view network connections" without it being listed in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, permissions, manifest

I just released my app in the playstore and saw that it lists the permission "view network connections", however i did not list this permission in the manifest, and also my app does not do anything network related. How can I disable this permission?

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxxxx.xxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeDark">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeDark"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".system_interaction.handler.share.BackUpActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>


        <receiver android:name="com.xxxxx.xxx.system_interaction.receiver.RebootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.xxxxx.xxx.system_interaction.receiver.NotificationReceiver" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please check libraries that you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go to the `AndroidManifest` and click on `Merged Manifest`. From there you could easily track from which library that permission comes.